# Accessing local Wifi network (without internet) with mobile LTE/3G

Tags: java, android, linux, networking, lte

I am working on an Android application through which I need to connect to a local Wifi Access point to get data while offering the user to be able to browse on his or her mobile data network.

While researching online, I have come across literature to modify the ip routing table through the "ip route add" command. So, for example, my Wifi access point is 10.100.100.100. The local Wifi access point dynamically assigns an IP address to my phone between .1 and .253 - so the command I ran through the adb shell on the device was:

```
ip route add 10.100.100.0/24 via 10.100.100.100 dev wlan0
```

This route gets added but when it does not help. Additional research has not provided any success. Programmatically, in the app, I cannot do the same. My Android phone is in dev mode.

Android is primarily Linux based and hence I fail to understand as to how I cannot create a route to a Wifi local access point while still having mobile data coverage.

I am sure I am missing something here. So, how I can gain access to mobile data, either programmatically or through a system configuration, while I am connected to a local Wifi access point which does not provide me internet access.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Because an Android application is sandboxed you won't be able to alter routing table from it, one way of doing what you want is to be root on your Android device. Then request root access privileges and add your routes

from `route` command:
`route: must be root to alter routing table`